# Lightning Component Action Error in Flow

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow

I have a lightning component that is supposed to refresh the record page. I have it implemented as an action in a visual flow, but it returns the following error:

"Error element Refresh_Record_Page (FlowActionCall).
We can't execute this action. Ask your admin to check that the "c:refreshRecordPage" Lightning component's client-side controller includes an "invoke" method and that My Domain is enabled and deployed for your org."

Here is the code for my lightning component:

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowActions">
   <aura:handler event="aura:locationChange" action="{!c.update}"/> 
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
 update : function (component, event, helper) {
  // Get the new location token from the event if needed
  var loc = event.getParam("token");
  $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
}

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use update screen component for this https://unofficialsf.com/the-update-screen-flow-action-component/

create a lightning component

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowActions,force:hasRecordId" access="global">


    <aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"
                    description="An error message bound to force:recordData"/>

    <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                      />

</aura:component>
```

js

```
({
    invoke : function(component, event, helper) {        
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            component.find("recordLoader").reloadRecord(true, $A.getCallback(function() {
                // ignore errors, we don't want to stop the flow if we cannot refresh the record
                resolve();
            }));
        });
    }
})
```

design

```
<design:component >
    <design:attribute name="recordId" label="RecordId"/>
    <design:attribute name="recordError" label="RecordError"/>
</design:component>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the recordError should be from the flow. I tried to call this lightning action from the flow but it doesnt refresh the page

Comment: @user81642 nothing just the "recordId" attribute

Comment: Can you please help me with the https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302508/refresh-the-page-after-flow-completes The lightning component called in the flow doesnot refresh the page

Comment: @user81642 i think it will only work if the flow screen is on record page

Comment: I am calling the screen flow from the button. Sorry I am not following you

Comment: @user81642 so when you click on button does it takes you to another screen to complete the rest of the flow

Comment: It is just screen where I am choosing the pick list value. Can you please look in to my question here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302508/refresh-the-page-after-flow-completes I have added the dtails

Comment: Can you please also explain why there is no recordId used in the in the controller JS

Comment: @user81642  we are using LDS we have just passed the id to force:recordData which is then refreshed

Comment: as i already said this will only work if you have screen placed on record page not when you click on a button and redirect it  to another page